# SharePoint Online create/view Custom notification using CSOM or JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, notifications

I wanted to create custom functionality similar to (see screenshot)SharePoint notification/facebook notification. E.g., if any of user(within organisation) like/comment on a list item, then it has to logged somewhere and show as notification at once place when author of the item logged in to SP online. I thought of adding each activity in custom list. But having ~50k emp at organisation, felt like custom list is not a good practice. Any suggestion to implement this please?
[image]